# Write $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}$ using summation notation

Tags: summation, notation

How does one write $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}$ using summation notation $\sum$? Use two indices ( and some sort of magic to indicate that the outer index should decrement)?

$$\sum_{\substack{i=0 \\ j=n-1}}^{\substack{0 \\ n-1}} x^j y^i$$

Is it possible to write it using only one index? *Should* it be written with only one index?

Comment: I'll fix that now.

Comment: Make sure you fix it in the body too, not just in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^{n -1-i} y^i
$$
But if you really want to use more than one index, you could try this:
$$
\sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} i,j\,\in\,\{0,\,\ldots\,,\,n-1\} \\  i+j = n - 1 \end{smallmatrix}}  x^i y^j
$$

Comment: Guh! Yeah. Thank you!

Comment: This is INCORRECT. The sum of exponents should be n-1, not n.

Comment: No, it is still incorrect. The first term was $x^{n-1}y$ - the $y$ was removed (the rest of the formula showed very clearly what the intent was). The sum of exponents is still n-1.

Comment: @mathguy : The sum of the exponents in what I wrote is $n$.  And so it has been since I posted it. $\qquad$

Comment: Exactly, AND IT SHOULDN'T BE. If you would spend a little more time reading the post and understand what was meant, instead of drive-by answering, we wouldn't have this exchange.

Comment: More like if I had bothered to post the right question from the beginning... Sorry about that, guys!

Comment: The question has been edited since I first posted this, and I have since edited the answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @mathguy I can see how you could possibly be annoyed here, but I think you are unnecessarily aggressive and overstating your case somewhat. (Please refrain from using all caps...doing so only makes you look immature and unprofessional.)

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow - all I can tell you is that some of the comments have been deleted (as you can probably infer if you look at the sequence). I believe my comments were appropriate. Capitals - where I used them - were in my opinion called for. Annoyed? Yes. The answerer is a very high reputation member of the community, not a rookie. There is no excuse for this kind of drive-by posting. (I had actually given up on following this thread after my last comment, but since you addressed me, I thought it rude to pretend like I didn't see it). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may help to note what is implicit here; namely
$$
S=x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^0+x^{n-2}y^1+\cdots+x^1y^{n-2}+x^0y^{n-1}.
$$
Then it is rather straightforward:
$$
S=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-i}y^i.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give this to @Michael Hardy, though: he answered first. ( I wrote the wrong question, he answered that correctly. Then, I corrected my question--and he answered correctly again. What a trooper. )

Comment: Simply choose whichever one actually answered your question and which answer you thought most helpful (that is the idea behind choosing answers right?). Regardless, it seems like you know what you are doing now. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's solved already I'll just leave here this $\dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$

Comment: Was that edit really necessary? Seems a little overbearing to use your privilege to make a largely stylistic change imo.

Comment: @Theoniix - I need to develop the intuition you used to recognize this was relevant: I'm reading Spivak's Calculus. My original question came from Spivak asking the reader to prove $x^n - y^n = (x - y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+ \cdots + xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ I'm guessing Spivak is getting at some fundamental property of mathematics here, but--which one? :/

Comment: By Opening the right side you get $$(x−y)\left(x^{n−1}+x^{n−2}y+\cdots+xy^{n−2}+y^{n−1}\right)=\\
=x\cdot x^{n-1}-y\cdot x^{n-1} +x\cdot x^{n−2}y-
y\cdot x^{n−2}y+x\cdot x^{n−3}y^2-\cdots\\  \cdots -y\cdot x^2y^{n-3} +x\cdot xy^{n-2}-y \cdot y^{n-1}$$
Try to show everything but $x^n,y^n$ cancels.
-
Once that's out of the way it's similar to a Geometric Progression. This is how I at least "recognized" it when I saw it for the first time. Other than that I don't think there's much intuition here though.